# Delete item from dataarray

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a script in which the row data of a google sheet is stored into a JSON. I'd like to filter the data that is stored in the array.I don't want the empty cells to be inserted into the array. I want only the filled cells to be inserted into the array .Here is the script I'm using

```
  var dataArray = [];
  var rows = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  for(var i = 0, l= rows.length; i<l ; i++){
    var dataRow = rows[i];
    var record = {};
    record['name'] = dataRow[0];
    record['age'] = dataRow[1];
    record['weight'] = dataRow[2];

    dataArray.push(record);   
  }
```

Comment: How do you know if a cell is empty or not?

Comment: The cells are copied from another sheet. So, the array records all the copied range even if the cell is empty.

Comment: Right. And you want to filter out empty cells. So, how do you know if a cell is empty? Will `dataRow[0]` be `undefined` for example?

Comment: I found elements like this in the array    "name":" "

Comment: What does the rows array return? Please log it to the console and add the code.@AhmadSayedAbdulrahman

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-do-i-remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Your link is about an array with one row and many columns but my array is n*n

@LloydNicholson

Comment: @AhmadSayedAbdulrahman can you reply to my question above then so I can try help you.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're really looking for is the [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to get rid of the empty cells, and then you can use a [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform them:

```
var rows = sheet.getRange(
  2,
  1,
  sheet.getLastRow() - 1,
  sheet.getLastColumn()
).getValues();

var filteredDataArray = rows.filter(function(row) {
  return row[0] !== ''; // Based on your comment that "empty" means it's an empty string
});

var transformedDataArray = filteredDataArray.map(function(row) {
  return { name: row[0], age: row[1], weight: row[2] };
});
```